# How to do a 301 redirect using Coldfusion from www to http

Tags: .htaccess, coldfusion, http-status-code-301

I did one of these online SEO analysis checks on a website I am building. One of the issues identified is:

WWW redirection (301): no
For search bots website addresses with www and without it are considered as different pages. Adding redirection help you avoid double content panelty.

In my current .htaccess file I have the following:

```
# lose the www
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I am not sure if the issue identified relates to the .htaccess file or something else?

I am using Coldfusion and all the searches I have done refers to 301 redirection but it seems that this relates to specific pages that need to be permanently redirected?

The code that I have found for Coldfusion 301 redirection is the following:

```
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved Permanently">
<cfheader name="Location" value="http://www.example.com/coldfusion/tutorial">
<cfabort>
```

My question is how do I set up the 301 redirection as identified above? Do I add the coldfusion 301 redirection as per the code above, and if so how do I use it to redirect users from www.example.com to http://example.com?

Or, must this be done in the .htaccess file and how should I structure it?

Hope this is clear?

So, in summary, how do I fix this problem:

*WWW redirection (301): no
For search bots website addresses with www and without it are considered as different pages. Adding redirection help you avoid double content panelty.*

Comment: Canonical host is something your webserver should do, so you are doing it correctly with the `.htaccess` in your Apache. Honestly, I don't see any mistake here. But just to make sure: Request your website using the `www` subdomain. Does the console show you a 301 redirect to `example.org` (without subdomain)? If yes, everything is fine and your "SEO analysis" tool is simply not detecting it properly.

Comment: I did what you suggested @Alex. The site is not redirecting if I go to www.example.com. How do I fix that?

Comment: Do you have a line `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess` before the 3 lines you posted?

Comment: Make sure your Apache is configured properly. You need to enable the rewrite module, tell the engine to use it (as Marthinus suggested) and - of all things - make sure Apache reads your `.htaccess` files. I think recent versions of Apache HTTPD disable them by default (security reasons). You may want to move your question to the ServerFault network as this is more of a server related question now.

Answer (score 1):

The method was not correct. This is the correct way to redirect from www to http.

```
RewriteEngine on

# lose the www
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is working perfectly now.